# Sound waves as an adiabatic process and defining pressure inside vibrating columns of air

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, waves, acoustics, adiabatic

In a MIT OCW video a professor goes on to derive the sound wave equation.

For this he takes a horizontal air column and assumes a pressure difference at its end which drives the gas column to the right as shown below (photo from his actual notes). [image]

Now he assumes this process to be adiabatic and hence applies the adiabatic equation ( i.e
$p v^{\gamma}=c$) . He applies this equation when the gas column has drifted to the right and hence writes $(p+\delta P)(v+\Delta V)= C$ where he says $\delta P$ is the change in pressure inside the gas column.

Since there is an unbalanced pressure at the two ends of the column I think that it means that the gas inside isn't at equilibrium (the left side is more compressed than the right), therefore we cannot define pressure and hence cannot write the above equation.

Could anyone please tell me where I'm wrong.